# Best way to refresh parent component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, parent-child, page-refresh

I have an Error Management page (parent) that pops up a modal (child). In that modal is a Delete button.

Here is the method for that delete button...

```
public async deleteAsync(): Promise<void> {
    
    try {
      await this.http.delete<any>('https://localhost:7168/api/ErrorManagement/DeleteError/').toPromise();
      this.fetchData();
    } catch (error: any) {
      this.notifyService.showError("Unable to delete " + this.whatYouWantToDelete);
    } finally {
      // Close the modal
      this.bsModalRef.hide();   
    }

  }
```

After I hit the delete error endpoint, I call the fetchData() method. It is available in the modal because I had sent it from the parent (Error Management page) to the child (modal).

Here is the code for that...

```
public async fetchDataAsync(): Promise<void> {

    try {
     window.location.reload();
    } catch (error: any) {
      this.pageLoadError = JSON.stringify(error.message);
    }

  }
```

Right now, I'm using `window.location.reload()` to try to refresh the parent (which has a list of the errors) **AFTER** the child (modal) has deleted one of the errors.

Per my example above, what is the **best way to refresh a page** (parent) after a modal (child) has closed?

Comment: Refreshing the page reloads the app. Your parent component should rely on data from a service which gets updated by the child. Is there any particular reason you __need__ to refresh?

Comment: Link the close dialog method to a parent method that retrieves the server data again, if you want more detals tell me and I post the code.

Comment: Yes, I need to refresh the page because when the page refreshes, it makes an API call to collect all the errors. When I delete an error, the list has changed. So I need to make another call AFTER the modal closes to refresh the list of errors.

Comment: What I need is for the parent page to be "made aware" that the modal window has closed and that an error has been deleted so that it can than hit the API endpoint that collects all the errors (which will have been updated since an error had been deleted).